# How to dispatch fetched data from API?

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

I have `fetchWeatherData(location)` - this file fetch data from weather `API`

When I call `store.dispatch(fetchWeatherData('london'))` all works correctly

But, how can I do this without `store.dispatch`...? I mean automaticly

Comment: Check: https://redux.js.org/api-reference/bindactioncreators

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something called `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   fetchWeatherData: (payload) => {
      dispatch(fetchWeatherData(payload))
  }
});
```

Now you need to `connect` this to your component and use it inside this.

```
class Test extends React.Component {

   componentWillMount () {
      this.props.fetchWeatherData("london")
   }

   render () {
    return null;
  }
}

const withStore = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps);
export default withStore(Test);
```

You can read more about this in redux [documentation](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/bindactioncreators).